# Joomla title & introtext hover image in category blog

Tags: joomla, overriding

i tried to override blog.php and blog_item.php with some css 3 image effects in joomla category blog view but had no success at all.

I want the article title and introtext as an image hover caption in the blog view.

Thanks for your help
Peter

Comment: You need to elaborate more. What did you actually do (some code), what happened, what did you expect to happen...

Comment: I tried to integrate this effect: http://miketricking.github.io/dist/ - Hover effect 1. I'm loading the css styles but can't figure out where to place the div's in blog.php and blog_item.php